# error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Tags: flutter, dart

i will import images BASE64 stored in DB.

code :

```
profileimage()async{
    var userimage1 = await DBHelper().getuserIMAGE1('roro');
    print(userimage1);
    if(userimage1 == Null){
      print('Empty');
    }else{
      setState(() {
        userimage1.map((e) {
          tmpimage = e['image0'];
        }).toList();
        print(tmpimage);
        _TmpBytesImage = Base64Decoder().convert(tmpimage);
        print(_TmpBytesImage);
        return Image.memory(_TmpBytesImage);
      });
    }
  }
  File pimage = profileimage();  << error
```

and i got error 'flutter: Only static members can be accessed in initializers'

how can i do?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot No , runtime error

Comment: This error indicates that you are accessing non-static members in a constructor, but you did not share a constructor :/

Comment: @killerwhale Are you calling your code in initState() ? if yes then you can use Future.delayed in initState() it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call like below.

```
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
           // your code 
        });
```

Comment: The error message was disappear, but it didn't data anything.....

Comment: @killerwhale I think the issue in profileimage method.

Answer (score 0):

The following items appear wrong:

1. Your return statement is inside a setstate() function so returns a value from that function.
2. processImage probably should be

Static Future processImage()

3. The call should be something like below but not at class level. It also needs to of type Image not of type File.

   pimage = await processImage();
4. If there is nothing in the database, what do you want to return?